# Does multiplayer progress carry over between platforms?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I play ME3 on xbox and a friend has it on PC. I know we can't game together between platforms but I was wondering if I bought ME3 on the PC is there any way that I can use the same profile that I use with xbox so I have the same classes and weapons unlocked without having to start over again? I'm thinking not but I thought it worth checking...

Comment: I haven't tested with the xbox version, but I know from personal experience that the WiiU multiplayer data does not transfer to PC (I have a separate profile for each multiplayer platform).

Comment: @user2414268: Cheers. I'd be surprised if it was any different for other platforms but I'll live in hope. ;-)